# Where is the deployment directory in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a web app in Eclipse. where is the deployment directory tree situated? In the Apache directory structure or some sub-directory tree structure in my Java workspace tree? I ask because I went browsing the directory tree(s) when an update to my tutorial app didn't work and, assuming that the **src** subtree represents my development directory tree I was hoping that the **WebContent/WEB-INF** subtree would contain my deployment tree (I also assumed that when I run the app the deployment directory structure would be automatically created for me), but I found the WEB-INF empty.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I'm developing a web app in Eclipse. where is the deployment directory tree situated? In the Apache directory structure or some sub-directory tree structure in my Java workspace tree?

It all depends on how your Tomcat Server is configured. The default should be: `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0`. But you can change this in the Tomcat server configuration. To do so, go to the **Servers** view, **double-click** on your Tomcat server and modify the **Server path** and **Deploy path**:

[image]

I personally use the Tomcat installation for full control (and the default deploy path i.e. `wtpwebapps`).

If it is not possible to change something in the "Server Locations" section, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012459/465304) on how to change that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Exactly what I needed. Except for one thing... That whole server location Option is greyed out for me so I have no access to it. I'll try find out why.

Comment: Resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012378/eclipse-server-locations-disabled-and-need-to-change-to-use-tomcat-installation

Comment: Where is this default directory found?  In the eclipse directory?  The project directory?  Home directory?  I can't find it in any of these on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Eclipse compiles into directories in the workspace. Once the build is complete, this directory is then copied by a deployment plugin into the directory Tomcat uses.

If you use the WTP plugin bundled in the Eclipse Java EE download, the deployment location is configurable in the server's property page within eclipse.

Comment: I use the wtp plugin. However I'm not sure how to get Eclipse to update when I make changes to the app. Like adding a class or a JSP. These changes weren't reflected in either directory tree when I went looking. I should mention that I was doing this manually before hearing about eclipse and then download it to use it as a development platform.