# Determing local publish location using RAD(Eclipse) + Commerce + WebSphere

Tags: eclipse, websphere, rad, websphere-commerce, wcs

I'm new-ish to websphere and want to find some jsp's deployed onto my local server from within RAD. How do I figure out what that location is? What folder do apps get deployed to on websphere?

**Edit:** I think that some of the standard approaches to look at Eclipse's "Server's" configuration will help me sort this out. Considering  "http://stackoverflow.com/q/3515089/977087" and "http://stackoverflow.com/q/1012378/977087". So this is a possible duplicate.

Will need to make sure there isn't any project/workspace deployment scripts in existance too (WebSphere Commerce project in RAD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the original JSP's or the compiled ones?

The latter are sometimes useful for debugging, and are found in the WAS profile dir under `<wasprofiledir>/temp/<hostname>/<server>/<app>/...`