# Tomcat webapps directory in windows

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, servlets

I am right now using eclipse to develop a simple web application and I am using Tomcat as web server. I have configured Tomcat in Eclipse and my application runs fine.

My question is: **where does Tomcat store the web app and in which folder does it store the classes?** I wanted to check the JSP to servlet conversion and wanted to verify how that converted file looks like and I am trying to find where exactly Tomcat stores the web app. I went into the webapps folder where Tomcat was extracted but my webapp is not in that folder.
Can someone tell **where I can find the converted JSPs?**

Comment: btw, might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515089/where-is-the-deployment-directory-in-eclipse

Answer (score 8):

right-click on the web project and select **Run As** then **Run Configurations...**

From the **Arguments** tab, the tomcat deploy path is provided as a **VM argument** with the name `-Dwtp.deploy`

Comment: thanks ahmad .. got a hint from ur link in the comment. The server path helped in finding the location.

Comment: Anyone know how can I change it. It strange that its using a location of another use. i.e. my username is X but its using c:\Users\Y\blabla.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the location. 
Double clicked on tomcat server inside eclipse and got the server path. something like this ..
C:\EclipseWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0

The location of the web app will be in the .metadata folder inside eclipse workspace (chk server path) and the converted jsp files can be found in location as given below.

serverpath\work\Catalina\localhost\loginApp\org\apache\jsp

@Admins ... This question can be closed or what ever action needs to be taken.

Thanks.

Comment: you know, you can delete your own question if you find it duplicate or something :)