# Can't deploy application to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I tried to start with Tomcat 7.
I created the application in Eclipse. Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">

<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>
  view.jsp
 </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>/servlets/myServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I downloaded the lastest Tomcat from Apache's site, and added `JAVA_HOME` to `catalina.bat`. After starting Tomcat I went in `Manager app` and chose my application but got 404. In the address line - `http://localhost:8080/ThreeRest/`.
Another strange thing is that the application didn't deploy into `webapps` directory but into `wtpwebapps` folder.

My other problem with `tomcat-users.xml`. If I add this:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

Its work only in one session. When I stop tomcat it is removed from file.

Comment: Are you deploying the application directly from eclipse?

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj: Yeah. I click `Run on Server` in `Run As` menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515089/where-is-the-deployment-directory-in-eclipse this will resolve few queries.

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj: I already have cheacked radio button like in `Pascal Thivent` answer. But this radiobutton group desabled anyway.

Comment: Let's debug one step at a time. If you manually move your web-app into webapps folder are you able to access it? (Try removing auth related stuff for now.)

Comment: As mentioned in the below answer, first you should correct the way servlet class is defined in web.xml, because the current configuration is not correct.

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj: Can you give example correct config?

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal: You mean deploy as WAR file?

Comment: No, simply move `wtpwebapps/your-app` to `webapps/your-app` to see if the app is serving the `myServlet` correctly or not.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal: i deploy app as WAR into wabapps folder but get 404 again(. But if i go to `http://localhost:8080/rest/myServlet/` i get blank page.

Comment: You needed to move the folder instead of deploying as WAR. Reason being wtpwebapps would conflict with webapps. Just rename your web-app folder in wtpwebapps for now. Restart the tomcat. Verify that you have myServlet at `<tomcat-home>/webapps/<your-web-app>/WEB-INF/classes/servlets/myServlet.class`

Comment: Access your servlet at `http://localhost:8080/<your-web-app>/myServlet`. web-app name should match the folder name above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<servlet-class>` should be

```
<servlet-class>servlets.myServlet</servlet-class>
```

because you specify a package here not a path.

Please note that you must access your website at either

```
http://localhost:8080/ThreeRest/myServlet
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/ThreeRest/
```

with `view.jsp` at your web-app's root folder.

**EDIT**:
Once deployed your web application's folder structure should be like: (`/` indicates a directory)

```
tomcat-home/
 |- webapps/
   |- rest/ //<-- Context-Root (Web-app's name)
     |- view.jsp //<-- *.html, *.jsp files
     |- WEB-INF/
        |- web.xml
        |- lib/
          |- *.jar files
        |- classes/ //<-- ALL your servlets go here
          |- servlets/ //<-- with the required package/folder structure
            |- myServlet.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a sample config, for servlet declaration:

Let's assume you are creating a servlet (HelloServlet which is in package x.y.z):

So code is something like:

```
package x.y.z;

//imports here

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

....Code here

}
```

Now in web.xml if I want to map this servlet I will do something like:

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
           x.y.z.HelloServlet
     </servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This is suffice, once app is deployed in tomcat, say the context name is **testservlet** , then I can access this servlet like:

```
 http://<ip>:<port on which tomcat is running>/testservlet/myservlet
```

Comment: Thanks for config. I try to get access on `http://localhost:8080/rest/myServlet/` and get blank page. If i have `view.jsp` as main site page how to get access to it?

Comment: @KliverMax You can't have a `/` after `myServlet` and wasn't your app's name `ThreeRest`? Please verify you use the same name at all places i.e. if `rest` the your app's folder under `webapps` should also be `rest`.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal: Now i deploy by WAR files. So in tomcat application name = name of WAR file. I have success. I remove `view.jsp` from `WEB-INF` folder and put it into WebContent directory. I can get access to it on `http://localhost:8080/rest/view.jsp`.

Comment: @KliverMax Good. (Had already mentioned about `view.jsp` in my answer.) Now just follow my last two comments on your question to access your `myServlet`.