# Jersey, Tomcat: The requested resource is not available error

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat7, jersey-2.0, rad

I have been working towards getting a RESTful service set up using Jersey and Tomcat in RAD 8.5. I have looked at tons of stackoverflow questions related to my error with none of them working. There are no errors in my console.

When I just type: http://localhost:8080/, I get the Apache homepage, so the server is working, but http://localhost:8080/jersey/rest/hello or http://localhost:8080/jersey/WEB-INF/classes/jersey/Hello.java
does not work.

Here is the error: (with my library of jars on the side)
[image]
Here is my `Hello.java`

```
package jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

      // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
      }

      // This method is called if XML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
      }

      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
      }
}
```

And my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Versions:

- Tomcat: 7.0.663
- RAD: 8.5
- Jersey: 2.19

Thanks,

**In Response to Maciej**
This worked! I needed to add `<servlet-mapping>` with url pattern of `/*`. Then use http://localhost:8080/jersey/hello, I got a response from the server!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="jersey" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are deploying a compiled code to Tomcat, so you won't be able to access the *.java resources.

Annotation `@Path("/hello")` indicates the path at which resource is available.

It is set to: `base URL + /your_path`. The `base URL` is based on your application name, the servlet and the URL pattern from the `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="jersey" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also replace `@Produces` annotation to `@Consumes`:

```
package jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

      // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
      }

      // This method is called if XML is request
      @GET
      @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
      }

      @GET
      @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
      }
}
```

Try: http://localhost:8080/jersey/hello

Comment: Same thing happens, `The requested resource is not available`

Comment: Try to configure the servlet mapping to match: `jersey/*`

Comment: Im going to answer in my question

Comment: `servlet-mapping` tag should defined on the same level as `servlet`

Comment: Now my server will not start. I get a couple of  `Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jersey]]` errors

Comment: Sorry, the servlet mapping should match `*` (or remove it). You need to verify `base URL`, it should be same as name of the war archive or folder in the Tomcat `webapps`.

Comment: In the Tomcat server? or where i installed Tomcat? because i cant find a war file anywhere =/.

Comment: If you run from Eclipse check this post for details on location of the deployment folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515089/where-is-the-deployment-directory-in-eclipse

Comment: One more thing: there is an error in the package configuration where Jersey scans for packages: `<param-value>com.example</param-value>` should be set to `<param-value>jersey</param-value>`. I'll update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: I found a war file, it is sample.war. how do i reference it in <url-pattern>? like so `<url-pattern>docs\appdev\</url-pattern>`?

Comment: just did, still nothing, in order to run the server i had to comment out your servlet-mapping addition, it stopped my server from starting.

Comment: I've updated the post: servlet mapping has to be set to `/*`. Also there was a slight change in Hello.java regarding annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Even after following the steps as mentioned by Maciej, if it says 404 resource not found, Mention the subclass that implements Application class and write it within init-param tag in web.xml

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>packagename.java_class_name</param-value> 
    </init-param>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have kept all the required Jersey Jar files in "WEB-INF -> lib" folder

Answer (score -1):

This problem solved by these steps

```
 1. Select all files in lib folder and right click on it

 2. Then click add to build path
```