# How to change tomcat default deployment directory in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

By default eclipse deploy tomcat app to

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\

Where do I change this, I can't see any parameter to do this in server properties in eclipse ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
window -> show view -> server
```

In the opening window, you should see your tomcat installation.
double click on that an a new setting page will open.

You will see the `Server Locations` title, you can set it from that place.

EDIT:

There are three radio boxes in this window.
You need to choose appropriate option for you to change the deployment directory.
Probably the last one will be better : "Use custom location(does not modify tomcat installation)"

EDIT 2:

[Eclipse "Server Locations" section disabled and need to change to use Tomcat installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012378/eclipse-server-locations-disabled-and-need-to-change-to-use-tomcat-installation)

Comment: In this window I cannot update server location it's greyed see picture I uploaded!

Comment: I cannot select last radio button :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919846/why-tomcat-server-location-property-is-greyed-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Basically whenever you ask the web container to deploy, it is not your responsibility to handle this anymore and you should not tinker with it.

What is the problem you are looking at?