# Why tomcat server location property is greyed in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to change server location but I can't it's greyed (I cannot select last radio button) how can I do it then:

[image]

Answer (score 146, accepted):

On the `Servers` view, delete all the webapps published under your server (right click on the server > `Remove` or right click on the server > `Add and Remove` and  then remove manually the webapps) and finally right click on the server > `Publish` (the 'empty' content). This way you would un-gray the *Server Locations* area.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instruction as I'm totally rookie at eclipse it works perfect :)

Comment: you may need to make a clean on the server (context menu)

Answer (score 12):

```
One way to change the server location is by doing the following steps:

    1)Right click on the Server(Example Tomcat server).
    2)Go to Properties.
    3)Click on "Switch Location" , in the "General" tab.
    4)The "Location" information changes.
    5)Now go back and the settings will be enabled to change the Server Locations
```

Answer (score 11):

As the dialog says : "Server must be published with no modules present to make changes." 
Stop the server remove any modules. After that the options will be enabled.

Comment: You must command the server to publish after removing the modules.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still dont see the option enabled, start the tomcat and then it will be enabled.