# Having trouble with installing Apache Tomcat 8.0.9 in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to install Apache Tomcat 8.0.9 in eclipse Kepler Service Release 2, Standard version.

I searched to find a way and I found I can add it from Server option. Tutorials telling me to add tomcat by going to the "Servers" option in the workbench,then adding new server.

After clicking that a page "Define a New server" will come,and from there I've to chose Apache tomcat. But the problem I'm facing is Apache Tomcat is not showing in my "Define new server" option. But according to the tutorials it should be there.The only server it showing is Google App Engine.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse you have? Eclipse standard or Eclipse Java EE version?

Comment: Do you have to use Kepler? [Eclipse Luna for Enterprise Edition](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar) seems to supports Tomcat 8 without problems. From this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse it seems that Kepler doesn't support it.

Comment: Kepler Service Release 2, Standard

Comment: I think this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always download Tomcat and install it separately. Then when you add new server in Eclipse just search for the folder that you installed tomcat in and select it.

Comment: Actually I did this. But when I searched tomcat is not found.

Comment: First, start Eclipse and go to the Workbench. Then, click on Servers tab at bottom. (If you don't see Servers tab, add the tab via Window, Show View, Servers.) Right-click on Servers tab, New, Server, Apache, Tomcat vX(7,8..), navigate to the folder where you unzipped Tomcat (e.g., C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\). You should now see "Tomcat vX.0 Server at localhost" listed under the Servers tab at the bottom.

Comment: - from here http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Comment: problem is when I Right-click on servers tab, option it shows is close. So I clicked the link to create new server and searched tomcat using Configure runtime environments. But even that didn't work.

Comment: re-install latest J2ee kepler? Sorry man I haven't seen this problem.

Comment: Mine is Kepler Standard version,could it be the root cause?

Comment: Oh maybe. I always use JEE version