# How to add Tomcat 8 to Eclipse Kepler without installing the big whole WTP package

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

Ok I am running with Eclipse Kepler. Tried today to set it up for Tomcat 8, but the adapter won't appear in the list.

Googled a bit and found tutos on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse), [nixmash](http://nixmash.com/java/adding-tomcat-8-in-eclipse-kepler/) and [vitalflux](http://vitalflux.com/add-tomcat-8-eclipse-kepler/), which all sum up the same way: download the last 3.6 Eclipse WTP and unzip it in your eclipse directories.

But I don't want a whole upgrade of my Kepler to the Luna WTP version (In my understanding, this is what would actually happen). I am looking for a way to pick only the server adapters. How do I do that?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

After experimenting by myself, I came up with the following solution:

- Go to the "Install New Software..." menu

[image]

- Use the Luna WTP url but select only the adapters (http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna):

[image]

- Wait for the dependencies to be resolved:

[image]

- Complete the installation process, restart Eclipse, try to configure a new server:

[image]

Hope this helps..

Comment: It worked with version Kepler Service Release 2 in my pc.

Comment: This worked great when even overwriting my wtp plugins/features didn't work

Comment: Worked for me too on my Kepler Service Release 2. I am also looking for addition of tomEE. Any clue on that?