# How to use tomcat 8 in eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-juno, tomcat8

Hi Is Tomcat 8 available for Eclipse Juno? If yes then how can I configure tomcat 8 with eclipse Juno?

I have tried and found this solution:

**[How to use tomcat8 in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse)**

But its also not working for me. I tried all the answers of this above question. But none of them worked. 
Any Solutions please?

Comment: Is there any reason why you haven't upgraded to Eclipse Luna?

Comment: Actually i have never used Luna so just wondering if it can be done in juno.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Its server adapter ships as part of the Web Tools Platform, and the version supporting Tomcat 8 is part of Luna.