# Installing Apache Tomcat 8 on Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse Version: Luna Release
I want to use Apache Tomcat 8 (I'm always working with the 7th version of Tomcat). When i try to define a new server from : Prefereces > Server > new Server i don't get the Apache Tomcat 8 in the showed list of different versions. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you use Luna indeed? [Luna ships with WTP 3.6](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna) which should have Tomcat 8 support.

There are similar questions on SO (e.g. [How to use Tomcat 8 in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17868232/131929)) and usually the solution is to update your WTP installation.

Help -> Install new software -> Add -> WTP:http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/ -> OK

Then Help -> Check for update.