# Apache Tomcat v8 is not showing in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy Apache Tomcat v8 in Eclipse Juno. Under define new server option, I see different versions of Tomcat(screenshot below), but there is no v8.

[image]

Can you please tell me how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think Eclipse Juno has Tomcat 8 bundled, but more recent versions of Eclipse do. Is that an option? Otherwise you'd probably have to manually configure Tomcat 8 first. There is this related (old) question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse

Comment: I think installing the latest version of Eclipse would be much easier and less problematic. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find Tomcat 8 bundled with Eclipse since **Mars** version or, if you want to keep using your current version, you can download the [Web Tools Platform plugin](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) in zip format and overwrite features and plugins directories with the ones you got from the WTP.

Answer (score -1):

According to me, you should not waste your time to find a particular plugin, just install Eclipse Mars.2 With this, you will get Apache Tomcat 8.0.