# Apache Tomcat 8.5 is not available in Eclipse EE IDE (Kepler) for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: eclipse

I've installed Eclipse Java EE IDE (Kepler) for Web Developers in Ubuntu 18.04. I also have Apache Tomcat 8.5 running and add this to my Eclipse. However, when I go to Preferences > Server > Runtime environments I can only see up to Tomcat 7 for selection, how do I add Tomcat versions above this?

Comment: you are using an earlier version of eclipse than mars, but have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse ?

Comment: Why don't you use the latest version of Eclipse (i.e. **Photon Release Candidate 3 (4.8.0RC3)**)?

Comment: Wow... Kepler -> Luna -> Mars -> Neon -> Oxygen -> Photon. Why are you using like 100 years old Eclipse :)?

Comment: I see. I did have the latest version installed but realised I need to have Java EE setup. I didn't realise before that was an option during installation but instead went and downloaded Java EE (and I see now is an old version, still trying to understand Eclipse). Thanks, I have later Tomcat versions showing now.