# Spring MVC http status 404 error

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting this error after typing url 
localhost:8080/HelloWeb

```
HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWeb

type Status report

message /HelloWeb

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
```

I am not able to solve it please help someone
 here are my files which are needed to do execute this SPRING MVC hello program

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

and here is my project hierarchy

HelloWeb 
 src
   com.tutorialspoint
 WebContent
   jsp
     hello.jsp
   META-INF
     MANIFEST.MF
   WEB_INF
     lib
     HelloWeb-servlet.xml
     index.jsp
     web.xml

sorry, i forgot to include that i following this Spring MVC example from

**tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm**

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong URL. The correct URL is localhost:8080/hello or localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello, depending on how you're deploying.

Comment: no sir @atamanroman i am using URL localhost:8080/HelloWeb/ but as soon as i enter Http status 404 error comes.

Answer (score 0):

when you hit the url `localhost:8080/HelloWeb/` it needs a landing page to display something which you can specify in the web.xml. Add this to your web.xml under the

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

but if you need to access the servlet you need to specify the url as
`localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello`

Comment: I want to display servlet but as soon as i enter localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello but then again error Http Status 404 comes

Comment: what do you mean by display servlet and your url must be  localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello HelloWeb with uppercase H

Comment: moreover you are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your HelloWeb-servlet.xml

Comment: display mean to access servlet in browser and i am typing same URL localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello but getting error

Comment: include the thing i told you in the above comment

Comment: ya i included it HelloWeb-servlet.xml but again i am getting same error.

Comment: one more thing remove the RequestMapping from the class level and add this `@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)` above your method printHello

Comment: sorry for the late response, i have added RequestMapping suggested by you above method printHello but i am getting that error AGAIN...........

Comment: did u remove it from the class level?

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but i too had same problem, because i also took code from tutorialspoint.com

try adding this in your `HelloWeb-servlet.xml`

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

This will enable annotations

and as well include this in your `web.xml`

```
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered that my jsp name had a space. The example from tutorialspoint works perfect as is.

Comment: this is more a comment than a real answer, since you are only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is very old, this is for the sake of other that may face the same challenge.
Your url mapping is not properly mapped. Use this as your controller. notice the change is just 'hello' to 'helloWeb' the name in your Controoler (@RequestMapping("/hello")) should be the same as the name in your web-app (
      HelloWeb
      /
   )

```
 package com.tutorialspoint;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/HelloWeb")
    public class HelloController {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code...

```
`<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />`

it shows that you have folder 'jsp' inside the 'WEB-INF' .
```

But you don't have a folder there as by looking at your project hierarchy.

Hence, change your code into below:

```
`<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />.`
```

Answer (score 0):

As @SparkOn pointed out, that the demo is missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

I make a working version on [github](https://github.com/yujiaao/HelloWeb), so anyone refered to this page can checkout it and run it with `maven`, as following:

build with maven

```
mvn clean package jetty:run-war
```

and go to browser, input `http://localhost:8080/hello`

you will see

```
 Hello Spring MVC Framework!
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into similar problem and followed few steps to resolve the issue. Though its very old post the solution may help others :-)

The steps I followed to solve the problem

1.Check the server configuration
   you should get  Tomcat Homepage for http://localhost:8080/ else follow the below link
[Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8085/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8085)

2.[Why tomcat server location property is greyed in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919846/why-tomcat-server-location-property-is-greyed-in-eclipse)

3.Dont forget to set the Deploypath to webapps

4.Right clich project->RunAs->RunOnServer

5.go to browser, input http://localhost:8080/yourApplicationName/yourPath

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the Request Mapping here

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```