# Tomcat 7 resource not available

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I followed the instructions here to configure [Tomcat 7 in Eclipse](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html).  As suggested there, I copied the `webapps/ROOT` directory to the eclipse workspace's `wtpwebapps/` directory and I can see the tomcat welcome page now. I was also able to get the test-app project (downloadable from that link) working.

Then to see the examples, I also copied the webapps/examples directory to the wtpwebapps directory and then restarted tomcat in eclipse. But when I try accessing examples via `http://localhost:8080/examples/` , it gives me a 404 error.

What more do I need to do to get the above working ?

Comment: https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need context entry for `examples` in `Server.xml`. The default application of a fresh install of Tomcat 7 is `ROOT`. So, It is not required to make entry.

Go to `Package Explorer--> Server --> Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config --> server.xml`

`Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config`, This may be differ in your case.

Add `Context` entry for `examples` web application.

Here is the sample entry of my `server.xml`

And I have copied examples directory to `wtpwebapps/` and added entry for like this

```
 <Context docBase="examples" path="/examples" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:examples"/>
```

Restart Tomcat server and you should get `http://localhost:8080/examples` working.

Also read @BalusC 's answer : [HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/) is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267/localhost8080-gives-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available)

Comment: @Vivek: Good to hear that.. :)