# Tomcat in Eclipse is giving error 404:requested resource not found

Tags: java

I am making a project in Java which is a online web application. I am facing issues with Tomcat 8 and jsp, if I try to run my jsp files on server it gives an error that 404:requested resource now found.

I tried every way given on you channel but nothing helped. Now I'm at an stage I have configured the server 100 times and nothing helps. I created a new project on other workspace and copied everything there and then run those jsp files it executed well for once and then after that when I stopped the server it again started giving the same error.

Whenever I restart the server the server does not start and gives error Tomcat failed to start and then when I remove my project below the server name it starts. If I configure new server same happens.

I can't figure out where the problem lies as earlier I was able to run my project using same Eclipse Luna IDE.

Comment: The server failing to start is an important bit of info, why is it failing to start, what's in the logs (catalina.out, etc)?  Any exceptions?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @AlexC Its giving an servlet lifecycle exception

Comment: Just post all the information, we can't help you unless you provide as much information as possible.  Right now you are saying it throws exception on startup, but you have not posted the startup log, or the exception, or the code, or anything else useful.

Comment: @AlexC will post it soon

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems you need to configure eclipse to take control from Tomcat.

Maybe this can help as well: [HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/) is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267/http-status-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available)

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion but this didn't help i have already tried  this