# Tomcat server webapps

Tags: java, tomcat

i Install tomcat 9.0. when i run localhost:8080 it is working fine. Under webapps folder i made Beer-V1 folder and made form.html file. when i try to acess the form.html file in browser it shows 404 error. Help me plz how can i access the form.html file?? (localhost:8080/Beer-V1/form)

```
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/Beer-V1/form] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is your folder structure? how about your case sensitivity? how can we help if we see nothing?

Comment: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\Beer-V1\form.html = folder structure ].......... when i run this [http://localhost:8088/Beer-V1/form.html]  error occurs. shows this [The requested resource [/Beer-V1/form.html] is not available].......i have checked properly about case-sensitive.. no error... May be somekind of permission problem ????

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The URL which you are hitting is incorrect, you are missing adding **.html** with a filename like in your case "form.html".

it should be **localhost:8080/BeerV1/form.html**.

Also, you can refer [here](http://www.herongyang.com/JSP/Tomcat-My-First-HTML-Page.html) for basic tomcat deployment.

Comment: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\Beer-V1\form.html = folder structure ].......... when i run this [localhost:8088/Beer-V1/form.html] error occurs. shows this [The requested resource [/Beer-V1/form.html] is not available].......i have checked properly about case-sensitive.. no error... May be somekind of permission problem ????

Comment: localhost:8088/Beer-V1/form.html - just to confirm, previously you mentioned 8080 port, now 8088 .

Comment: Also, try making index.html file under webapps folder and see if is coming up or not. In that way you can confirm your server doesn't have any problem and then later check under your Beer-v1 folder.

Comment: i have changed port to 8088. localhost:8088 and localhost/8088/docs is running but after adding index.html under webapps it is not running. [http://localhost:8088/index.html] = 404 error

Comment: plz ans i get stuck

Comment: Does http://localhost:8088 is showing any homepage. Is your server getting started correctly ?

Comment: yes it shows.. congratulation page,... Congratulation you have successfully install tomcat.

Comment: Can you check if any of these solution works for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267/http-status-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available