# Error 404 - the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

I'm very new to Java, I'm attempting to create a very simple Rest API to return a string via a GET method. I've been through countless tutorials, but each time I get the above error using my project

url - http://localhost:8080/orchestrator/api/service/status

I'm using the ApplicationConfig.java - ApplicationPath file to denote the mapping:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

/**
 * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
 * It is automatically populated with
 * all resources defined in the project.
 * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
 */
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(com.orchestrator.Services.class);
} }
```

Using Netbeans 12.6 with Tomcat via XAMPP v3.3.0; I have a web.xml but apparently I don't need it as I'm using the ApplicationConfig.java, but I'll post the one I made.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>.com.sun.jerysey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.orchestrator.Services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Services.java

```
@Path("/service")
public class Services {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

public Services() {
}

@Path("/status")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getHtml() {
    //TODO return proper representation object
    return "connected";
}
}
```

Project Structure:
[image of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEONW.png)

What am I missing to return the "connected" text, I've also tried using postman as well to return, same result.

Regards

Comment: Show me please, how ur web.xml looks like?

Comment: the web.xml is the second code block in the main post. Further exploring has shown that my project is deploying to tomcat -> work -> Catalina -> localhost. Shouldn't this be in webapps?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling a wrong route.

Your applicationPath begins `/api` and
not `/orchestrator/api`

You can try with this route `http://localhost:8080/api/service/status`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work using http://localhost:8080/api/service/status - browser returns - Message The requested resource [/api/service/status] is not available; The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: What was returned when you try to reach http://localhost:8080

Comment: It returns the Tomcat main page; XAMPP also confirms it's running Tomcat on 8005, 8080

Comment: you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267/http-status-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available