# Configure Eclipse + tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

How I can enable the Server Locations options ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012378/eclipse-server-locations-disabled-and-need-to-change-to-use-tomcat-installation

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably running. Stop the server and these options should become updatable