# SpagoBI AxisFault

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404, apache-axis

I am trying to integrate SpagoBI into my existing web application via the .jar files inside the SpagoBISDK.

1. I downloaded their All-In-One-SpagoBI which consists of their BI Server which is already configured with apache tomcat 6.0.18. It worked fine as I tested it via this link on the web browser: localhost:8080/SpagoBI
2. After which, I download their sample project, SpagoBISDK.war. When I placed the .war file inside the "BI server-configured" apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps folder and start tomcat. It worked fine as I tested it via this link on the web browser: localhost:8080/SpagoBISDK.
3. Link to download All-In-One-SpagoBI: http://forge.ow2.org/project/download.php?group_id=204&file_id=18770
4. Link to download SpagoBISDK: http://forge.ow2.org/project/download.php?group_id=204&file_id=18561

Note: the All-In-One-SpagoBI is required for the SpagoBISDK to work. In addition, the SpagoBISDK.war is like a sample web app project.

**Problem:**
When I import the SpagoBI.war as a project into Eclipse, use the "BI server-configured" apache-tomcat-6.0.18 to run the project, I encountered the following error:

```
INFO: Server startup in 444 ms  
AxisFault  
faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP  
faultSubcode:   
faultString: (404)Not Found  
faultActor:   
faultNode:   
faultDetail:   
{}:return code:  404  
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /SpagoBI/sdk/TestConnectionService</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/SpagoBI/sdk/TestConnectionService</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource (/SpagoBI/sdk/TestConnectionService) is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.18</h3></body></html>  
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:404  

(404)Not Found  
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)  
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)  
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)  
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)  
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)  
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)  
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)  
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)  
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)  
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)  
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)  
at it.eng.spagobi.sdk.test.stub.TestConnectionServiceSoapBindingStub.connect(TestConnectionServiceSoapBindingStub.java:100)  
at it.eng.spagobi.sdk.proxy.TestConnectionServiceProxy.connect(TestConnectionServiceProxy.java:67)  
at org.apache.jsp.documentsList_jsp._jspService(documentsList_jsp.java:95)  
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)  
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)  
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)  
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)  
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)  
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)  
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)  
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I googled for similar problems faced by other people. And many mentioned that the links to the web services are incorrect. However, I tested the links via the web browser by running the SpagoBI.war file inside the webapps folder (Step 2 as mentioned above) and they worked fine.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain to me why is that so and hopefully, how can I go about resolving the issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to my problem, I have already solved it.

1. By default, Eclipse uses "Use workspace metadata (does not modify Tomcat installation)". You have to change the server location to "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation) in order for the SpagoBI SDK sample project to work after you export it into Eclipse. See link - [Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8085/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-...-to-link-to-http-localhost8085)
2. In case you are unable to change the settings, someone else provided an instruction on how to do it. See link - [Eclipse "Server Locations" section disabled and need to change to use Tomcat installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012378/eclipse...nge-to-use-tomcat-installation)

Hope this helps!