# Unable to start Tomcat server instance

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run a project, but till now can't get it work properly.
The database connection string is a JVM parameter in the tomcat server instance startup towards AWS amazon web server.

but when I try to run it I get these errors

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java: 202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.j ava:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:3 06
```

I have Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Kepler Service Release 1 running on MAC os and Tomcat v7.
I am trying to check the functionalities of an already created project using `DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING`.
It is the first time for me to check a web service, so I am not sure what else needed to make the connection!

It is a new instance I have just created after downloading Tomcat v7, using
`Preferences -> Server -> Installed Runtimes` to create a Tomcat installed runtime, then I added a new server and pointed the the installation directory to the downloaded source. I'm still not sure about the JRE library (I have two options default and javase6); I tried both but with same result.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set: 
“Use Tomcat installation (take control of Tomcat installation)”

[image]

If Server Location is disable follow the instruction of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012459/3002676):

> 1. Right click on my tomcat server in "Servers" view, select
>      "Properties…"
> 2. In the "General" panel, click on the "Switch Location" button.
> 3. The "Location: [workspace metadata]" bit should have been
>      replaced by something else.
> 4. Open (or close and reopen) the Overview
>      screen for the server.