# Unable to access the tomcat server from a browser even when the server is started thru eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, eclipse-kepler

I have Apache Tomcat 7 server. which I have linked into my Eclipse IDE. Now, I have some observations.

1. When I start the server thru Eclipse, I am not able to start it using "Configure Tomcat" in bin folder and its the other way too.
2. When I start the server thru "Configure Tomcat", I can access the localhost URL using browsers(firefox etc) but not the browser which is in Eclipse.
3. When I start the server thru Eclipse, I am neither able to access the server thru browser nor thru eclipse browser.

Are these expected behaviour? or Is there something I am missing?

Any help in this regard is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Eclipse, you need to change server locations

Comment: Are you using a proxy, or have a firewall configuration in the way?

Comment: @Zealous : there is only one server on my machine which is only used for eclipse as well.

Comment: @nitind : No idea. Please let me know in case you need any info.

Comment: Checkout your server configuration, Double click on your server check tomcat configuration-> "Server Locations" must be selected "Use tomcat installation" option.

Comment: @Zealous : server path shows the entire server folders are present. Should I set something on the deployment path also?

Comment: @PavanKumar refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012378/eclipse-server-locations-section-disabled-and-need-to-change-to-use-tomcat-ins