# Getting error while starting Tomcat Server 9 in Eclipse though command line run is successfull

Tags: eclipse, tomcat9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZCee.png)I recently installed Apache Tomcat and am able to start Tomcat Server from command line but while starting from Eclipse I get these errors:

Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

I have java 10 and jdk jdk-10.0.1, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

I tried everything from these posts:

[Eclipse "Server Locations" section disabled and need to change to use Tomcat installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012378/eclipse-server-locations-section-disabled-and-need-to-change-to-use-tomcat-ins)

I could not find .snap file from this directory

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources to delete it

There is no temp file in this directory

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core it just has 2 temp folders

https://crunchify.com/ideal-eclipse-ini-file-setup-for-your-eclipse-environment-best-practice-for-macos-and-windows/

I also updated Eclipse Oxygen by launching link https://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/oxygen/ in Help to no avail.

Attaching some screens

I am held up testing my code so immediate help is appreciated.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcpyH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PJIJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kdOb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has already been fixed in Photon and newer: https://bugs.eclipse.org/533162

I'd also suggest a supported release of Java, like 11, instead of 10.

Comment: OK, so does this mean I upgrade to Photon and install java 11 and change the JRE System Library for all my projects? AND change the JDK HOME params in Path too?

Comment: At the least, just update to a newer release of Eclipse. The rest you can do on your own schedule--Java 10 will work, it's just not a supported release by Oracle any more.

Comment: Hi, I installed Photon release software and now when Eclipse launches it still shows Oxygen. Also when I run Tomcat server Eclipse crashes. Here is crash report: Cant add it here its long. Waiting for an answer....

Comment: Then I'm not sure Photon was installed properly. You could try the *current* release, which today is 2019-09.

Comment: Situation is same. I installed 2019-09 and same error

Comment: Situation is same. I installed 2019-09 and same error. Added few images to main thread

Comment: You might have to remove the instance you have and define a new one.

Comment: I removed old instances and added new Tomcat server instance and still get the same error. Could someone help?

Comment: Also I have /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.30 as my Tomcat installation directory. Should it be /Library/Tomcat instead? BTW I tried both with same result

Comment: If shouldn't matter as long as you have the same layout as their downloadable zip files.

Comment: Can you remove the runtime from the preferences as well as the servers view?

Comment: Did that as well to no avail

Comment: No longer an issue in Java 13. Hence closing